# Can you copy a struct to another, when both are the same, unknown, type

Tags: c#, struct

Here is my first attempt.  I hoped that the last statement in Fill() would do a memberwise copy, but in fact nothing happened.  The issue is doubtless that the types in the assignment are not known at compile time.  My intent is to use a dictionary of structs, keyed by type, in connection with unit tests.  Maybe it can't be done, without adding knowledge of the various individual structs to my class.

```
internal class TestData
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, ValueType> mTestData = new Dictionary<Type, ValueType>();

    internal static void Add(ValueType _testData)
    {
        mTestData.Add(_testData.GetType(), _testData);
    }

    internal static void Fill(ValueType _runtimeData)
    {
        ValueType testData = mTestData[_runtimeData.GetType()];
        _runtimeData = testData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is working for me is to return the result:

```
internal static ValueType Fill(ValueType _runtimeData)
{
    return mTestData[_runtimeData.GetType()];
}
```

and call it like this:

```
parms = (NewRuleParms)TestData.Fill(parms);
```

Comment: And, yeah, I can just as well use classes as structs here, even if a different thing is happening underneath.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code. Value types are copied when passed as arguments and returned from functions:

1. In `Add(ValueType _testData)` the variable `_testData` will be a copy of the `ValueType` fields of the passed argument.
2. `_testData.GetType()` will always return `typeof(ValueType)`.
3. `_runtimeData = testData;` modifies the local variable `_runtimeData` but it cannot modify the passed argument.

Reconsider using generics and boxing value types. Here is the working modification of your code

```
internal class TestData
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> mTestData = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    internal static void Add<T>(T _testData) where T: ValueType, struct
    {
        mTestData.Add(typeof(T), _testData);
    }

    internal static void Fill<T>(ref T _runtimeData) where T: ValueType, struct
    {
        T testData = (T)mTestData[typeof(T)];
        _runtimeData = testData;
    }
}
```

Comment: #2 is not so.  I stopped in the debugger, and examined the dictionary entry.  The key is the specific struct name of the argument.

Comment: Are you sure that `ValueType` is struct?

Comment: Yes.  The idea is that various structs will be used as test cases are developed.  The target code defines them, and it would be great if the test code could just instantiate, fill in some data, and go.  Far down the line, the class using it will fill it from user input if not in test, otherwise pass its structure to this.